# What does %i or %I do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the meaning of `%i` or `%I` in ruby?

I searched Google for

```
"%i or %I" ruby
```

but I didn't find anything relevant to Ruby.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
%i[ ] # Non-interpolated Array of symbols, separated by whitespace
%I[ ] # Interpolated Array of symbols, separated by whitespace
```

The second link from my search results http://ruby.zigzo.com/2014/08/21/rubys-notation/

Examples in IRB:

```
%i[ test ]
# => [:test]
str = "other"
%I[ test_#{str} ]
# => [:test_other]
```

Comment: aka [the % notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation)

Comment: This is correct. I don't recommend using `%I` however.

Comment: @MarkThomas Why don't you recommend `%I` would you elaborate?

Comment: @ArupRakshit My guess is that it's ugly and can be much less clear than using a more obvious String interpolation.

Answer (score 34):

It can be hard to find the official Ruby documentation ([it's here](https://ruby-doc.org/)). At the time of writing the current version is 2.5.1, and the documentation for the %i construct is found in the documentation for [Ruby's literals.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html)

There are some surprising (to me at least!) variants of Ruby's % construct. There are the often used `%i %q %r %s %w %x` forms, each with an uppercase version to enable interpolation. (see the [Ruby literals docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html) for explanations.

But you can use many types of delimiters, not just `[]`. You can use any kind of bracket `() {} [] <>`, *and* you can use (quoting from the ruby docs) "most other non-alphanumeric characters for percent string delimiters such as “%”, “|”, “^”, etc."

So `%i% bish bash bosh %` works the same as `%i[bish bash bosh]`

Comment: just FYI, the [Ruby Style Guide](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/PercentLiteralDelimiters) calls for square brackets.

Answer (score 17):

It's like `%w` and `%W` which work similar to `'` and `"`:

```
x = :test

# %w won't interpolate #{...} style strings, leaving as literal
%w[ #{x} x ]
# => ["\#{x}", "x"]

# %w will interpolate #{...} style strings, converting to string
%W[ #{x} x ]
# => [ "test", "x"]
```

Now the same thing with `%i` and `%I`:

```
# %i won't interpolate #{...} style strings, leaving as literal, symbolized
%i[ #{x} x ]
# => [:"\#{x}", :x ]

# %w will interpolate #{...} style strings, converting to symbols
%I[ #{x} x ]
# => [ :test, :x ]
```

Comment: This answers the question more clearly. The usage of "%I" is just to create hash keys from an array of strings, separated by whitespaces. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @VishalKanaujia While symbols are often used as hash keys, that's not their only purpose. In Ruby a hash key can be literally anything, and symbols can be used in many other circumstances.